# SQL query which selects the last row from each day

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help. I have a table (senosrId, time, data), and I need to select the latest data from each day for one of the sensors for the latest 10 days.

Comment: well..try to solve it and post a question if you get stuck.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't resolve it for last week, that's why I posted this question and need some help.

Comment: Show what you've tried, then we can help you based on your code.

Comment: SELECT idsensor, max(time) as time_max, acetone from timegetdata GROUP by date(time) where idsensor=1 ORDER by time DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: and what's not working about that query? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on writing a question that's more likely to get answers

Comment: I have resolved this problem, it's my solution SELECT idsensor, max(time) as max_time, butan from (select * from timegetdata where idsensor=1)as help_table GROUP by date(time)ORDER by time DESC limit 10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For MS SQL, tested, compiled:

Test table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataTable](
    [SensorId] [int] NULL,
    [SensorTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [SensorData] [int] NULL
)
```

Run several times to insert demo data:

```
insert into DataTable (SensorId, SensorTime, SensorData) select 1, getdate() - 15*rand(), convert(int, rand()*100)
```

Get last value for each of the last 10 days (actual answer):

```
select top 10 * 
    from DataTable 
    inner join (    -- max time for each day
         select SensorId, max(SensorTime) as maxtime, convert(varchar(10), SensorTime, 112) as notneededcolumn 
            from DataTable
            group by SensorId, convert(varchar(10), SensorTime, 112)
    ) lastvalues on lastvalues.maxtime=DataTable.SensorTime and lastvalues.SensorId=DataTable.SensorId
    where DataTable.SensorId=1
    order by DataTable.SensorTime desc
```

Example output:

```
1   2017-05-17 21:07:14.840 54  1   2017-05-17 21:07:14.840 20170517 
1   2017-05-16 23:35:37.220 94  1   2017-05-16 23:35:37.220 20170516
1   2017-05-14 22:35:48.970 8   1   2017-05-14 22:35:48.970 20170514
1   2017-05-13 14:56:34.557 94  1   2017-05-13 14:56:34.557 20170513
1   2017-05-12 22:28:55.400 89  1   2017-05-12 22:28:55.400 20170512
```

Comment: it definitelly must work. I will create table and compile it... wait 1 hour pls, I am busy now

Comment: Ok, I'm waiting)

Comment: works as expected... I will update the answer with compiled query

Comment: I'm confused how this is the accepted answer since it's clearly written for MSSQL and the question was tagged MySQL.  Also, the OP has listed in the comments the answer written with MySQL syntax.